# (Unity) moving platform moves player weirdly

Tags: unity-game-engine

I got this code to move the player whenever he enteres the trigger of a moving platform to move him with it:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Moving Platform"))
    {
        previousPosition = other.transform.position;
    }
}
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Moving Platform"))
    {
        Vector3 distanceVector = other.transform.position - previousPosition;
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + distanceVector);

        previousPosition = other.transform.position;
    }
}
```

For some reason the player gets slowly pushed additionally in the direction in which the platform is moving. When setting the parent off the player to the platform it happens aswell and i need the set the player to kinematic so he moves, which creates issues with the movement. Giving the player a sticky physics material creates issues too.

The player is moved by adding forces and the platform is used with rigidbody.MovePosition().

Anyone has an idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"the player gets slowly pushed additionally in the direction in which the platform is moving" makes sense as [Rigidbody.MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) moves the kinematic Rigidbody towards position. So you are not setting the position directly as you would be doing with the transform. You might want to have a look to [Rigidbody.position](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-position.html) that has the same "teleport" effect as setting the transform directly.

To apply the movement of the platform to the player, as I think you want to do, I would make the player children of the platform, as when the parent is moved, all the children are moved along. You can manipulate your scene gameobject's hierarchy in the `OnTriggerEnter` and `OnTriggerExit` accordingly, so that the movement application of interest occurs with [Transform.SetParent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html).

Comment: First of all thank you for your ideas!
Making the player a children of the platform unfortunately didn´t do it for me, because for the player to then move i need to change its drag which again creates issues with the movement.
But the  i found out that the problem was that the platform was moved with RigidBody.MovePosition(). Using RigidBody.position, as you mentioned, fixed the moving issue, but now it appeares gittering when the player stands on it. Any idea how to fix that?